# How could I possibly debug "Couldn't find design note - undefined"?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

In an Xpages driven application I quite frequently see messages like this appearing at the server console:

```
HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - undefined [/myDbPath/myDb.nsf/undefined] Some Username
```

Quite often but not always this message is preceded by another weird warning

```
HTTP JVM: WARNING: CLFAD####W: State data not available for /myPage because no control tree was found in the cache.
```

(for the latter you may want to see my other [still viral issue regarding cache losing my pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482575/xpages-falling-out-of-server-side-cache))

So far no users have complained, but the latest release of the application has been published only a couple of days ago, so this makes me kind of nervous.

Question is: how could I possibly debug such a thing? Of course I couldn't find anything by the name of "undefined"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` is an indicator of a JavaScript (or Java) error in an XPage.

```
undefined [/myDbPath/myDb.nsf/undefined] Some Username
```

The first `undefined` in the line refers to a resource, it can be another XPage, a file in the Resources, an image file, etc..  This value is being calculated somewhere on the XPage and returning `undefined`.

The path `/myDbPath/myDb.nsf/undefined` is referring to the URL being requested.

To determine what XPage is causing the error, open the server's **Domino Web Server Log** (domlog.nsf) and find the date/time and user that matches the error time.  That should narrow down what XPage it is.

Then look to the JavaScript in the XPage and all its controls.

Debug from there ... ;-)

Comment: yeah is some part of your xpage computing a resource URL using ssjs? maybe this is where undefined is coming from.

Comment: thanks both @CameronGregor and teleman for your input; drilling down I think I found some kind of plausible explanation: each time a user opens a view-type xpage its pageName is stored inside a sessionScope var so that the user can return to the original source view after having opened a doc. Obviously sometimes this variable is kicked out of memory for whatever reason, and then it seems that the variable is still there (else my current error handling measures would strike) but somehow its content has no proper reference. At least that's what I observed so far.

Answer (score 1):

Are you syncing your NSF with an on-disk project? I've seen issues where that error is caused by problems with the config or metadata files for either the xPage or any custom controls it is using.   Clean the project first (Project - Clean menu option) then if that doesn't work make sure you can open all the relevant design elements in designer.  If you have issues there, examine the metadata and config files using the Package Explorer.

Comment: thanks for your input but it doesn't appear to be the issue here; see my comment further down below